# 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

why is my queryset throwing this error whenever i make a search to the backend of account object below the post have added the traceback ?

```
def auto_search(request):
    user = request.user
    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    payload = []
    if search_query :
        search_results = Account.objects.filter(email__icontains=search_query).filter(username__icontains=search_query).distinct()
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            # get the authenticated users friend list
            auth_user_friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=user)
            for account in search_results:
                payload.append((account, auth_user_friend_list.is_mutual_friend(account)))
                
        payload = serializers.serialize('json',payload)       
        return JsonResponse({'status':200 , 'data':payload})
```

Account model.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

friendlist models.py

```
class FriendList(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    friends             = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="friends") 
    
    # set up the reverse relation to GenericForeignKey
    
    notifications       = GenericRelation(Notification)
```

This is the traceback below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\game\views.py", line 35, in auto_search
    payload = serializers.serialize('json',payload)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 94, in serialize
    concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Can you please share the full traceback?

Comment: I just added the traceback to the code can you please have a look at it @WillemVanOnsem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using `django.core.serializers`. The second argument you should pass to `serializers.serialize()` has to be `queryset`, usually it's a list of models django queryset.

Here you are collecting your list for serialization:

```py
payload.append((account, auth_user_friend_list.is_mutual_friend(account)))
```

So each element of your list is tuple, which couldn't be serialized. Don't sure what you were exactly are going to do. But if you need list of accounts and `FriendList` has suitable method `is_mutual_friend`, you may wanted something like this:

```py
            for account in search_results:
                if auth_user_friend_list.is_mutual_friend(account):
                    payload.append(account)
```

That should work correctly.